# the two largest numbers in array of 4 elements

Tags: arrays, algorithm, assembly

I'm trying to find a way to find the largest two numbers in array of 4 elements, the approach I'm using right now is like this:
start with

```
x = array[1]  
y = array[2]  
compare x,y  
if y > x then switch the values "because i want x to have the greatest value"  
read array[3] if it greater than x then make it the new x and give x value to y  
else if check if it greater than y if yes then make it the new y
```

but there are too many comparison, and I want to reduce it. do you guys have better algorithm ?

Comment: Sort it and pull the last two elements out, i reduced your problem to a sorting problem

Comment: I'm using assembly to do it and I'm trying to do it with less instructions.

Comment: @JohnOdom Your suggestion is strictly C++, C doesn't have `std`.

Comment: If you were using C++ then you could of used std::vector<int> with std::sort(). See sort [C++ Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/?kw=sort).

Answer (score 1):

Yeah actually you will make a lot of comparisons for each index.
Why simply not find the maximum, remove it from the array then find the maximum ?

Your algorithm will be O(2n) so O(n)

Comment: The problem is stated for 4-elements array. Please don't involve big-O

Comment: He did not clearly stated if the array was always going to be 4 elements long or not. My point was just to show that sometime native and simple solutions do not have bad running time.

Answer (score 1):

The comparison-optimal algorithm uses 4 comparisons. Let the elements be a, b, c, d. Compare a and b, and c and d. Let e be the greater of a and b, and f be the lesser. Let g be the greater of c and d, and h be the lesser. The maximum is the greater of e and g. If it's e, the second maximum is the greater of f and g. If it's g, the second maximum is the greater of e and h.

Comment: You use 5, as "if it's e" is a comparison in itself

Comment: @Alter Only if you implement it poorly and repeat the comparison between e and g.

Comment: That would've been 6 the way I thought you meant, it looks like I just misread. Our answers are basically the same, since you posted first you can copy my graph if you want (I'll delete my answer then, I just like visuals)

Answer (score 0):

You want to use less instructions? As in the program using less or you writing less? I'm going to assume the prior.

Think of it as a tree.

To get the highest value you can use as few as 3 comparisons

A
...\____ E
.../...........\
B..............\
..................\______Highest
................../
................./
C............./
...\____ G
.../
D

To get the second highest node, you only need to compare the nodes that lost against the highest node.

Ex.
A is found to be the highest, we must therefore compare B and G to find the second highest.

Result: only 4 instructions needed

Answer (score 0):

Doing a bubblesort on this array would only require 6 comparisons. Because you're only interested in the 2 largest numbers you can cut the sorting algorithm short right after the second iteration thus avoiding the sixth comparison.
To improve performance put the array in registers EAX, EBX, ECX, and EDX

```
cmp eax,ebx
jl t1
xchg eax,ebx
t1:
cmp ebx,ecx
jl t2
xchg ebx,ecx
t2:
cmp ecx,edx
jl t3
xchg ecx,edx
t3:
cmp eax,ebx
jl t4
xchg eax,ebx
t4:
cmp ebx,ecx
jl t5
xchg ebx,ecx
t5:              ;ECX and EDX are the largest numbers
```